Why is the electric field of a coaxial cable independent from the outer shell in the inner region?
A coaxial cable consists of a positively charged inner cylindrical surface and a negatively charged outer cylindrical surface.
However, in between the surfaces, why is the electric field only dependant on the inner cylindrical surface, as can be derived from Gauss' Law for Electric Fields. Wouldn't the negative charges on the outside surface also produce an attractive force on a positive charge (force is analogous to electric field if the charge is constant)?
The forces from each surface are not equal and depend on the distance from the surface of interest, right?
Clearing this up may also help me to understand why there is no electric field inside in the inner cylindrical surface from the differing forces from both shells.
